# Replace Loops using Recursion

Tags: javascript

I really need a feed back on my explanations especially on 2) and 3). I just want to confirm if I understood it correctly or no since I am a newbie. 
This is a freeCodeCamp challenge which was really challenging for me because I have no experience with JS before. It goes as below.
Write a recursive function, sum(arr, n), that returns the sum of the first n elements of an array arr.

```js
function sum(arr, n) {
  if(n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
  }
}

/* 1) sum([1], 0) should equal 0.
   2) sum([2, 3, 4], 1) should equal 2.
   3) sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3) should equal 9. */

/* My explanations are down below */

/*
    Explanation 1) 
    sum([1], 0) should equal 0.
    n is less or equal to 0 so line 2 works and returns 0 at line 3.
*/

/*  Explanation 2) 
    sum([2, 3, 4], 1) should equal 2
    n is not less or equal to 0 so it will not return 0 according to line 2. We move to line 5.
    *return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
=>  return sum([2, 3, 4], 1 - 1) + arr[1 - 1];
=>  return sum([2, 3, 4], 0) + arr[0] => n is less or equal to 0 so it will return zero according to line 2.
=>  return 0 + arr[0]
=>  Since arr[0] is equals to 2
=>  return 0 + 2;
=>  2
*/

/*  Explanation 3)
    sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3) should equal 9
    n is not less or equal to 0 so it will not return 0 according to line 2. We move to line 5.
    *return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
=>  return sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3 - 1) + arr[3 - 1];
=>  return sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 2) + arr[2]; => n is 2, not less or equal to 0 so go back to line 5 + arr[2].
=>  return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1] + arr[2];
=>  return sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 2 - 1) + arr[2 - 1] + arr[2];
=>  return sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 1) + arr[1] + arr[2]; => n is 1, not less or equal to 0 so goes back to line 5 arr[1] + arr[2].
=>  return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1] + arr[1] + arr[2];
=>  return sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 1 - 1) + arr[1 - 1] + arr[1] + arr[2];
=>  return sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 0) + arr [0] + arr[1] + arr[2];
=>  return 0 + arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2];
=>  in our array, arr[0] is 2, arr[1] is 3, arr[2] is 4.
=>  0 + 2 + 3 + 4
=>  5 + 4
=>  returns 9
*/
```

Comment: Your function and explanations look ok at a glance, but this question is off-topic here. [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for feedback on working code, Stackoverflow is for getting help with code that isn't working.

Comment: your explaination is good. your function just sumup first n elements of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we can make it shorter:

```js
const sum = (arr,n) => --n<0 ? 0 : sum(arr,n) +arr[n]

console.log ( sum([1], 0) )
console.log ( sum([2, 3, 4], 1) )
console.log ( sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok, translation problem, I will try my hand at showing a recursive function

Comment: @NinaScholz I changed it for a recurssive one ;)

Comment: @MisterJojo you turned it into 1 line code. Well played.

Answer (score 4):

From logical view it looks fine. You could also try the ternary operator if you want to play around.

```
return n <= 0 ? 0 : sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
```

The first block is the if question. If its true is goes to the second block (starts whith ?) and if its false it goes to the third block (starts with :).

Comment: it could be shortend to `return n-- && sum(arr, n) + arr[n];`